# Solution for Dynamic Selection of Report Templates

Tags: java, jsf-2

My requirement goes like this,

When I select a template like **exam**, exam page will generated having exam fields(have respected POJO's) and when **Games** Page is selected, a page will generate with its fields,

How can I implement this type of requirement. main goal is, bean no need to bother which template is selected.It is completely independent.

Comment: Please, specify which type of template are you using and what kind of bean are you talking about? (ManagedBean / JavaBean / POJO).

Comment: @Guizzo:thanks for reply, I am using CDI bean

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the whole problem, but I'll try to help.
You may use `Template Method` design patter for your bean class, and in your JSF page, you can call the abstract class methods. Something like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractBean {

    public void templateMethod(){
         //Same code for all children;
         foo();
         //Same code for all children;
    }

    protected abstract void foo();
}

public class Bean extends AbstractBean {

    protected void foo(){
        //Your specific code here;
    }
}
```

And then, in your JSF page you may just call `#{abstractBean.templateMethod()}`. But I am not really sure how you can inject a subclass into `#{abstractBean}` variable.
Although, there is a Facelet tag which may help you in another way: `ui:param`. Take a look at this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/facelets-454361.html. There is nothing to do with the previous code, it's another solution. I already used it myself. You can define a variable in the template page (`ui:define`) and in the specific page you just use `ui:param` to set a value to the variable defined into the template page. Then you call `#{definedVariable.someMethod()}` I think these are the tags, I'm not sure.
Hope I could help.